# FrontPage Alternative?

Tags: windows, web-development

Currently, I’m using FrontPage 2003 to manage the “Master copy” of my (very large, now) web site ([Freelance Traveller](https://www.freelancetraveller.com)) and to upload updates to it. However, FrontPage does not run on Windows 10, and with Windows 7 having gone completely out of support, the time has come to find an alternative.

I’ve seen several suggestions, and am currently leaning toward [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org), but would like to “hear” what others have to suggest. There are features that FrontPage has that I would very much like to have in any replacement, though I haven’t found any alternative that claims to have them:

- Site structure awareness and management with TOC and “breadcrumb” generation.

  - TOCs should be available for the entire site, and for specific
    subsections. Ideally, since a page title is normally "Site Name -
    Section [- Subsection...] - Page Name", the TOCs should pick up only
    the "Page Name" part of the title.
  - “Breadcrumbs” would reflect the site hierarchy, picking up page names as above, for the string of links back to the home page. An acceptable alternative would be for it to pick up the page names of the various pages that the visitor actually visited to get to the page, but I suspect that such dynamic breadcrumbs would actually be harder to implement.
- Site-wide “recalculation” and update of inserted “last-edit” dates and “breadcrumbs” if a page is edited or moved within the site (e.g., due to restructuring).
- Upload via FTP, only new/changed pages. I would prefer that the webdev package handle this, but am not averse to a separate application - but the compare/identify new/changed pages is mandatory.

I don’t require FOSS, but I also have no objection to it; I *do* object to SaaS/recurrent license payments (so I am strongly disinclined to consider Adobe Dreamweaver).

The target OS for this is Windows. I am not currently considering shifting over to Linux, though this is not a *permanent* decision.

Comment: Have you thought about using a CMS instead?

Comment: @ThomasWeller - I'm not averse to the idea, but I'm also not exactly eager to try to convert a site that's well over a thousand pages...